# Disable "Ask The Community" on Salesforce Communities

Tags: community

Is there a way to disable the Ask The Community feature on Communities?

[image]

Many Thaks!

Best,
EF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue and I fixed by not providing Label for 'Discussion Tab Label' for Home Page Tabs component

[image]

And for Ask the Community Button you can hide it using Custom CSS, I am using below css.

```
.siteforceNapiliFooter #askCommunity {
    display: none;
}
```

You can add it in Branding Editing section:

[image]

Comment: I suppose this works. It seems kind of kludgey though. I'd like to see a secure way of disabling it, and on a per user bases. Not everyone in the community should be able to see discussions or ask questions.

Comment: Hi @ScottMorrison in that case you need to play with permissions for respective profile/role/group of users. There is no other way to do it as of now.

Comment: @BasantKumarverma - Sorry it took me so long to respond to this... Thanks for providing a solution! Aside from doing what you suggested, I also removed all the Lightning Components associated to Discussions from the page as as well, which seemed to work. Many Thanks!