# Disable Discussions on Salesforce Communities

Tags: community, community-builder, napili

Is there any way I can disable the Discussions tab from the Search Results component on Community Builder?

**Note:** I'm currently using Napili template

[image]

I've tried the answer on this post
[Disable "Ask The Community" on Salesforce Communities](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81932/disable-ask-the-community-on-salesforce-communities)

putting a blank label on for the tab, but it doesn't work for this component, it still defaults to the Discussions tab when the users redirects to this page even if it doesn't have any label anymore as you can see from the screenshot below. I just want it to default to the Articles tab instead of the discussion section. 
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the Active tab just to point to "articles"

Check below settings in builder

[image]

Here are results

[image]

Comment: Oooops. Sorry Mohith, posted the same time. i'll mark yours as best answer

Comment: I am getting you +1 as well.

Answer (score 3):

Someone from the salesforce success community has already answered my query and it did work!!

Here's the post from salesforce community. Credits to James Goerke

[Disable Discussions on Salesforce Communities](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?feedtype=RECENT&criteria=BESTANSWERS#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=Additional_Products&criteria=OPENQUESTIONS&id=90630000000ZiFYAA0)

> You can Default the Articles Tab to show up first on by changing the Active Tab to "articles".

[image]

Cheers,
Sean

Comment: Coincidence just posted same :)

Comment: I know right! haha All good mate. Marked yours as best answer. Cheers